# How to sum a variable number of rows in a column?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of integers sorted in ascending sequence from top to bottom.  Each integer appears multiple times in the column but no integer appears the same number of times.

Moving down the column, when the integer changes, I want to insert a row that shows the sum of the identical integers above the new row.

As I move down the column, I'm using a counter to count the identical integers (and my testing shows that the counter is working), 
but when I insert the counter into R1C1 format (third line from bottom below), it returns a zero.  Therefore, the summation that results is summing the current row with the one above it (a circular reference), rather than the top row containing the like integer with the one above it.

My code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Counter As Integer
Counter = -1
Range("F5").Activate
For i = 1 To 50
x = ActiveCell(1, 1).Value
y = ActiveCell(2, 1).Value
  If x = y Then
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Counter = Counter - 1
  Else
  Call subTotal
  Counter = -1
  End If
Next i
End Sub

Sub subTotal()
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[" & Counter & "]C:R[-1]C)"
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Pivot tables and sub-totals might be able to do that without the need for VBA - just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (sort of conditional "Running Sum") that you can use/modify pertinent to your case. Assuming for simplicity that all 10 values are in the Excel Worksheet Column A, then the "Running Count" will appear in Column B and "Running Sum" in the Column C:

```
1   3   3
1   2   2
4   3   12
1   1   1
2   2   4
4   2   8
5   2   10
4   1   4
2   1   2
5   1   5
```

Following is the simple VBA code snippet that does the job:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Counter = 0
    x = Cells(i, 1).Value
    For j = i To lastRow
        If x = Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            Counter = Counter + 1
            Cells(i, 2).Value = Counter
            Cells(i, 3).Value = Counter * x
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Also, a universal solution for any number of entries is shown below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastRow
    Counter = 0
    x = Cells(i, 1).Value
    For j = i To lastRow
        If x = Cells(j, 1).Value Then
            Counter = Counter + 1
            Cells(i, 2).Value = Counter
            Cells(i, 3).Value = Counter * x
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I needed to pass the variable called 'counter' to the subroutine called 'subTotal'.  Once I fixed that, everything worked fine.